# Extract decimal numbers from text column

Tags: powerquery, m

I am looking to extract the numbers of hours in a column TXT however PQ is unable to find a pattern due to the inconsistency in the structure of text. I have used Columns by Example but hasnt helped.

Is there a M code or combination of M code I can use?

Sample data:

| TXT |
| --- |
| Contract Staff w/e 26.06.21- Carer 9.5hrs- MNL |
| Contract staff w/e02.07.21 - Physio- 19.34hrs- ARK |
| Contract Staff w/e 04.07.21 - RN 13.25- MNL |
| Contract Staff w/ e 04.07.21 - carer 6- MNL |
| Contract Staff w/e25.06.21 - carer 12.5 - KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e04.07.21 - RN 34hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e04.07.21 - AIN 25.5hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e26.06.21- Carer - 6hrs- MNL |
| Contract Staff w/e11.07.21 - 6hrs- MNL |
| Contract Staff wie 24.06.21 - Carer 8hrs - ARK |
| Contract Staff w/e 16.06.21 - EN 5.50- GL |
| Contract Staff w/e 16.06.21 - RN 5.25- GL |
| Contract Staff w/e 11.07.21 - RN 22hrs- MNL |
| Contract Staff w/e 11.07.21 - carer 27.75- MNL |
| Contract Staff w/e04.07.21 - RN 22.25hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e04.07.21 - AIN 69.67 - KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e04.07.21 - RN 5.75- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e10.07.21 - RN 16hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e10.07.21- Carer 6hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e11.07.21 - AIN 38.50- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e18.07.21 - RN 46-KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e18.07.21 - AIN 17 -KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e18.07.21 - Cleaner 24.50 -KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e18.07.21 - AIN 19.5- MNL |
| contract staff w/16.07.21 - RN23.25hrs - MNL |
| contract staff WIE 25.07.21 - carer - 42.25hrs- MNL |
| contract staff w/E 18.07.21 - AIN 24.5 - KLTL |
| contract staff WIE 18.07.21 - Domestic 6- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e 13.07.21 - RN 6.25hrs- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e25.07.21 - RN 19.5- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e25.07.21 - AIN 13.5- KLTL |
| Contract Staff w/e18.07.21 - AIN 6hrs- ARK |

Comment: You may want to define the patterns you need and then combine multiple text functions to extract accordingly. For example, you could start with ```Text.BetweenDelimiters``` using “-“ as delimiters. With Regex it easier to define and extract according to pattern, but it is not supported by PowerQuery out of the box, so you may need another tool for that.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse..I know google sheets has REGEX functions.. Is there a place where I can get the reference on what REGEX to use to define the Patterns?

Comment: There are a few sites like this one where you can actually run your regex expression against a test string: https://regex101.com/  and you may start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops … there is e.g. an add-on for regex in Excel (but PowerQuery is not supported)

Comment: If you post sample input and expected output, someone will be able to provide a solution. There is a workaround to use REGEX in PQ but it is not recommended and quite slow.

Comment: Yes, OP can check Peter’s  edited answer below. It looks quite right to extract the numbers of hours.  I just mentioned regex as a more flexible alternative to modify/adjust, e.g. in case OP wants also to extract the substrings before the hours and after the hours or there are more “variants” of the string to extract from. While not supported in PQ out of the box, regex works directly as cell function with the add-on installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this:

1. Add column, extracting text after "-"
2. Remove all letters and remaining "-"
3. Convert text to number

```
#"Inserted Text After Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(
    Source, 
    "hours", 
    each Text.AfterDelimiter([TXT], "-"), type text
),
#"Remove Letters" = Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter", 
    {{"hours", each Text.Remove(_, {"A".."z", "-"})}}
),
#"Changed Type to number" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    #"Remove Letters",
    {{"hours", type number}}
)
```